# Key Layout change

Tags: keyboard, buttons, samsung-captivate-glide

My Captivate Glide's power button is broken, I was hoping to remap the a hardware key in the keyboard layout folder so that i may use a different key as the power button once the device is on. I was wondering if the change to the layout file would only be applied after boot or if i can use the assigned key to power on the phone as well?

Comment: Mr. Spock's logic suggests: No. As before the device is powered up, how should it read the contents of your keayboard layout folder?

Comment: @Izzy thanks for the reply, by extension that would mean kernel changes would have no effect either and the only other way would be a hardware modification. As there is no other solution short of repair, keyboard mapping will have to suffice. Thanks again for the reply.

Comment: That's correct, yes. Unfortunately, short of turning it in for repair, I see no other solution.

Comment: [Remapping power and volume keys](http://android.stackexchange.com/a/123017)